# Cannot find div close to selector

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the HTML structure below.
I'm trying to add text inside `invalid-feedback` within JavaScript:

```js
var form = $('#form');
form.find('.invalid-feedback')
  .closest('#email')
  .text("hello world");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email (*)</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" required id="email" />
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password(*)</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" required id="password" />
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

but I get no text inside the `div`. It seems like jQuery cannot find the selector.

This is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/12217/) test.

Comment: remove `.closest('#email')` !?

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() {
     var form = $('#form');
 form.find('#email')
      .next('.invalid-feedback')
      .text("hello world");
});`

Comment: @caramba I need to apply the text to the corresponding div, in this case is `email`, so not all the `invalid-feedback` div

Comment: You asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813707/how-to-find-an-element-near-a-selector

Comment: @Mohammad and ... I removed it for the following reasons:
1. I commit a mistake to write the selector
2. You and other users have downvoted the question without giving me the time to fix it
3. Next time, spend your time to be gentle instead of scan my deleted questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

UPDATE : based on the comment "@caramba I need to apply the text to the corresponding div, in this case is email, so not all the invalid-feedback div"

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
         var form = $('#form');
     form.find('#email').next('.invalid-feedback')
          .text("hello world");
    });
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/12219/)

hope this helps.